# Javascript expression bug (0 <= 14 < 10)?

Tags: javascript

How can this be true?

```
0 <= 14 < 10
```

I need to evaluate that a number is in between 0 and 10.

But this breaks my logic.

Shouldn't that expression be false?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This expression:

```
0 <= 14 < 10
```

is the same as

```
(0 <= 14) < 10
```

which is

```
1 < 10
```

true.

What you can do instead is:

```
if (0 <= x && x < 10) { ...
```

Python is the only programming language I can think of right now where the expression `x < y < z` does what you expect it to do.

Comment: And the solution is of course to write `0 <= 14 && 14 < 10` which will obviously evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Actually, C# and VB.NET do what they are supposed to do: throw a compile error. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug. It's the way the expression is parsed.

It goes left to right:

```
0 <= 14 < 10
true < 10
1 < 10
true
```

As you can see, `0 <= 14` is `true`, so that's what it's replaced with. `true` is equal to `1` in JavaScript, and most other C-derived languages.

---

What you should use is:

```
(0 <= 14) && (14 < 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

NO. That is true.

`0 <= 14` is `true (same as int(1))` and `1 < 10` is `true`

do this instead:

```
if(variable > 0 && variable < 10) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: It's L2R, isn't it? Or does it depend on the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

```
0 <= 14 < 10
(0 <= 14) < 10
true < 10
1 < 10
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression is not evaluating the way you expect it to. It's equivalent to

```
 ((0 <= 14) < 10)
```

So the first one evaluates and returns true, so you then have `true < 10`, and `true < 10` evaluates to true in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Also check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence